# Increase Height of TableRow on Drag

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm working on a JavaFX app via SceneBuilder and I'm trying to work with adding functionality to the TableView. My current task is to allow the user to drag and increase the height of each TableRow on drag. Essentially, I'm trying to make it function like Excel.

**Java Code**

```
    tv.setRowFactory(t -> {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        tr.setPrefHeight(54);

        tr.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            tr.setMinHeight(event.getY());
        });

        return tr;

    });
```

I tested the getY() function on drag and saw that it was iteratively increasing as I moved down on the screen.

I tried searching for a way to do this, but I couldn't find any leads on this. If you have a link to some documentation on the methods that are required, that would be great as well.

Also, if SceneBuilder has a built in way to allow for this functionality in a TableView, that may work as well.

Comment: Did you visited Oracle`s Java FX docs? 

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableRow.html

Comment: I did see that. There is a check for isResizable, but there is no setResizable function for the Control.

Comment: Check `resize` method. Isn`t you loking for?

Comment: I need to do it in a way that recognizes which direction the drag is going.

Comment: Yes I tried the `resize` function as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
table.setRowFactory(t -> {
            final TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            final double prefHeight = 54;
            tr.setPrefHeight(prefHeight);

            tr.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
                final double newHeight = event.getY();
                if(newHeight < prefHeight) {
                    return;
                }
                tr.setPrefHeight(newHeight);
                tr.autosize();
            });

            return tr;

        });
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers!